# Bundle /service override chain in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony

Is there a possibility to construct bundle override chains in Symfony2?

For example, there is a `CoreFeatureX` in the product core. And there are two plugins extending that feature `PluginA` and `PluginB`.

Using standard methods from [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html) or from [here](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/bundles/override.html) plugins can override `CoreFeatureX` no problem. But only one of them at a time can currently do that.

Is there a possibility to automatically construct override chains so that if both `PluginA` and `PluginB` registered in the system, they can both extend `CoreFeatureX` (may be, by inheriting from each other automatically) but be unaware of each other?

Similiar extension technology is used by XenForo forum system, for example. XenForo constructs an inheritance chain from plugins, that were registered as some core class extensions. It then exposes the topmost class of the extension chain as that core class itself.

Comment: Do I understand you well, that you would like to register bundles `CoreFeatureX`, `PluginA`, `PluginB`, where plugins are defined to  extend `CoreFeatureX` directly, but as a result get bundle inheritance chain like `CoreFeatureX` extended by  `PluginA` extended by `PluginB`?

Comment: @dragoste Exactly. The exact order of extension is unimportant. It could be `CoreFeatureX` extended by `PluginB` extended by `PluginA` for example. But the requirement is for both `PluginA` and `PluginB` to extend `CoreFeatureX` and to be unaware of each other.

Comment: I think it'd translate better if you add sudo code

Comment: @ThomasPotaire Sorry, but what is "sudo code"?

Comment: Sorry, always wrote it as sudo code, it's [pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode). For example, you could represent the inheritance using a tree represented by `|` and `-`

Answer (score 0):

Since Symfony2 doesn't let us to extend the same bundle twice at the same time, you can't to that in "clean" Symfony2.

This is clearly implemented in `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel::initializeBundles()` here:

```
protected function initializeBundles()
{
    // (...)

    foreach ($this->registerBundles() as $bundle) {
        //(...)
        if ($parentName = $bundle->getParent()) {
            if (isset($directChildren[$parentName])) {
                throw new \LogicException(sprintf('Bundle "%s" is directly extended by two bundles "%s" and "%s".', $parentName, $name, $directChildren[$parentName]));
            }
            //(...)
            $directChildren[$parentName] = $name;
        } else {
            $topMostBundles[$name] = $bundle;
        }
    }

    //(...)
}
```

I guess this is for a reason. Anyway you could try to override `Kernel` class behavior of `initializeBundles` method (in `AppKernel` class). In the line where exception above if thrown, you could change parent bundle from `CoreFeatureX` to the last in chain.

In case of `PluginB` change parent bundle to `PluginA` because it already extends `CoreFeatureX`.

In case of `PluginC` change parent bundle to `PluginB` because it is on the end of current inheritance chain.

I don't know if it could work, it's just an idea. Anyway that would be an interesting experiment. ;-)

Edit.
I just notined in your comment to the question that you wrote:

> But the requirement is for both PluginA and PluginB to extend
>   CoreFeatureX and to be **unaware of each other**.

Well there's something wrong here. How do you want to override one plugin by the second and on the other side make them unaware of each other? Doesn't make sense for me.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. About extension - they should both extend `CoreFeatureX`. If they extend each other - this should be seen as implementation detail and be taken care of by framework. This can be achieved by using Proxy classes for example for transparent inheritance.

Comment: You said you want to achieve a **chain**. Now you're saying they should both extend `CoreFeatureX`. I'm now confused about what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I am sorry for being unclear. Once more: I want to build a plugin system, where plugins can independently extend core features. XenForo does this by constructing an inheritance chain, that allows to simulate some features of Aspect Oriented Programming around your core classes. What can Symfony suggest? With default extension technologies, only one Bundle at a time can extend some core object.